# JMockit: mocked collection of beans doesn't work with Stream API

Tags: java, jmockit

I have a simple method that needs to be tested using JMockit but it seems that using Stream API requires additional mock but I don't understand what exactly I have to add.

The method that works using `for-loop`

```java
private final List<ValueProcessor> valueProcessors;

public List<Response> proc(Entry value) {
    List<Response> badResponses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ValueProcessor processor : valueProcessors) {
        List<Response> responses = processor.process(value);
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(responses)) {
                badResponses.addAll(responses);
        }
    }
    return badResponses;
}
```

The same code with usage of Stream API:

```java
public List<Response> proc(Entry value) {
    return valueProcessors.stream()
            .map(processor -> processor.process(value))
            .filter(collection -> !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(collection))
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)           
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I want to test the code using `JMockit`, so I have the following test

```java
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class ProcessorTest {
    @Injectable
    private List<ValueProcessor> valueProcessors = Collections.singletonList(processor -> Collections.singletonList(new Response()));
    @Tested
    private Processor processor;

    @Test
    public void testProc() {
        assertThat(processor.proc(null)).hasSize(1);
    }
}
```

The test always passes for method with `for-loop` and always fails for method with `Stream`. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, when you create the list of `valueProcessors` using `@Injectable` you're creating a mock of a list.

That means that the methods of the said list will be mocked so that they will return "empty" values by default (if nothing is specified via `Expectation` blocks).

So on the first, non-stream code, as no methods are called on the list, no problem arises.

But, on the second stream-using code, the call to `valueProcessors.stream()` executes the "empty" mocked behavior that returns an empty stream, and so, everything else goes empty too.

The solution I've camed up with is to create the tested instance passing it a "real" list, instead of a mocked one:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class StackOverflowTest {

    // empty injectable just so that the processor can be created
    @Injectable
    private List<ValueProcessor> valueProcessors;

    // availableDuringSetup = true to be able to modify the processor
    @Tested(availableDuringSetup = true)
    private Processor processor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // create new instance of the processor (now the valueProcessors list is a real list)
        processor = new Processor(Collections.singletonList(processor -> Collections.singletonList(new Response())));
    }

    @Test
    public void testProc() {
        assertThat(processor.proc(null), hasSize(1));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alfergon! It is exactly what I need!